# Errors when using realloc()

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

I am using `realloc()` to dynamically size some arrays. Because I was writing a lot of code like this:

```
void *tmp;
if( (tmp = realloc(myobject, sizeof(object) * newsize) != NULL)
         myobject = tmp
```

I thought I'd make my code shorter by doing something like this (silly idea):

```
void GetSpace(void *ptr, size_t size_of_object, int newsize){
    void *tmp = NULL;
    if ((tmp = realloc(ptr, size_of_object * newsize) == NULL)
          //print error msg and exit
    else 
         ptr = tmp;
}
int main(){
    //This is an example
    double *mydata1 = (double *)malloc (sizeof double * 5);


    //later request more space for mydata1 
    GetSpace( mydata1, sizeof(double), 50);

}
```

This is silly since it doesn't save that many lines or make the code more readable but I'd like to know why it doesn't work the way I expect. When I use the `GetSpace()` for a single object only it works fine. If I run the code without initializing any of the objects I call the function with, it runs fine but when I call `GetSpace()` for an object, then put data in it and then call `GetSpace()` for another object, I get a stack trace with a message like this

```
*** glibc detected *** ./a.out: realloc(): invalid old size: 0x00007fff05d96790 ***
```

`0x00007fff05d96790` is the address of the second array/object before resizing. Why does this happen?

Answer (score 3):

In your `GetSpace` function, you are allocating a new block of memory with the bigger size, and assigning the address to the local variable `ptr`. But when the function exits, this new address is lost. Your main program still has the old value of `ptr`, which is now pointing to invalid (freed) memory.

You need to return the new address to the caller. Try this instead. Note that the parameter `ptr` is now passed by reference, so the caller's variable is updated.

```
void GetSpace(void **ptr, size_t size_of_object, int newsize){
    void *tmp = NULL;
    if ((tmp = realloc(*ptr, size_of_object * newsize) == NULL)
         //print error msg and exit
    else 
         *ptr = tmp;
}
```

**EDIT:** as pointed out in the comments, this still isn't ideal, as you have to do messy casting to pass the address of your pointer as a `void**`. An improvement would be to return the new pointer separately, as follows:

```
void *GetSpace(void *ptr, size_t size_of_object, int newsize){
    void *tmp = NULL;
    if ((tmp = realloc(ptr, size_of_object * newsize) == NULL)
        //print error msg and exit
    else 
        return tmp;
}

int main(){

    ...

    //later request more space for mydata1 
    mydata1 = GetSpace( mydata1, sizeof(double), 50);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that now you can't pass `&mydata` when calling this function - the types do not match, `double **` is not compatible with `void **`. One is forced to either use an extra intermediate `void *` pointer, or to use a cast `(void **) &mydata` (which is a hack). A better solution would be to use the return value of `GetSpace` to return the new pointer, instead of using a `void **` parameter.